# Cannot get anything from .Core Web API

Tags: c#, api, http, asp.net-core, webclient

So, I had encountered next problem.

1) Creating new asp core 2.1 app (template MVC)

2) Adding new controller:

```
[EnableCors]
public class ApiController : Controller
{
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return $"You sent {id}";
    }
}
```

3) Enabling CORS in Startup.cs:

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin());
```

4) Creating classic/.net core console app with next code:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AsyncMethod();
        }

        private static async void AsyncMethod()
        {
            Task.Delay(5000).Wait();
            var http = new HttpClient();
            var url = "https://localhost:44353/api/get/4";
            var response = await http.GetAsync(url);
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
```

If I add code directly in Main() or even create WPF/UWP/WinForms app and paste this code there, still nothing works. Both (classic and .core) console applications just exit debugging without any exceptions or messages and only in debug window I see

```
The program "[10340] dotnet.exe" ended with code 0 (0x0).
Program "[10340] dotnet.exe: Program Tracing" ended with code 0 (0x0).
```

Replacing this code with using WebClient didn't help. Moreover, with classic ASP MVC 4 application this code works great, so my console app is correct. But this code doesn't work with .Core app.

postman and RESTed client perfectly see api and can send requests without any problems.

What am I missing?

Comment: Your problem is `async void`. You don't *wait* for the asynchronous task to complete before exiting the application.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.opa.kg/uploads/posts/2009-08/1251278848_podborochka-kartinok_37355_s__22.jpg

In a case if someone will face this problem.

1) Delete line

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin());
```

2) Replace decorator

```
[EnableCors]
```

With

```
[EnableCors("*"]
```

3) Make sure that you are'nt trying to use `async void` (thank  **Kirk Larkin**).